# Input range in filter is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

In the mobile version of the site the input range does not work in the filters if you click on it.Everything works fine on a laptop. In the mobile version of the site the input range does not work in the filters if you click on it.Everything works fine on a laptop.

https://svitlanavorobets.github.io/toster/catalog.html

Javascript:

```
setTimeout(init2slider('id66', 'id66b', 'id661', 'id662', 'id66i1', 'id66i2'), 0);

function init2slider(idX, btwX, btn1X, btn2X, input1, input2) {
    var slider = document.getElementById(idX);
    var between = document.getElementById(btwX);
    var button1 = document.getElementById(btn1X);
    var button2 = document.getElementById(btn2X);
    var inpt1 = document.getElementById(input1);
    var inpt2 = document.getElementById(input2);
    const firstInputValue = document.getElementById('id66i1')
    const secondInputValue = document.getElementById('id66i2')
    if (!inpt1) return
    var min = inpt1.min;
    var max = inpt1.max;

 
    var sliderCoords = getCoords(slider);
    button1.style.marginLeft = '0px';
    button2.style.marginLeft = (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth) + 'px';
    between.style.width = (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth) + 'px';
    if (!input1.value && input2.value) return
    inpt1.value = min;
    inpt2.value = max;


    inpt1.onchange = function (evt) {
        if (parseInt(inpt1.value) < min)
            inpt1.value = min;
        if (parseInt(inpt1.value) > max)
            inpt1.value = max;
        if (parseInt(inpt1.value) > parseInt(inpt2.value)) {
            var temp = inpt1.value;
            inpt1.value = inpt2.value;
            inpt2.value = temp;
        }


        var sliderCoords = getCoords(slider);
        var per1 = parseInt(inpt1.value - min) * 100 / (max - min);
        var per2 = parseInt(inpt2.value - min) * 100 / (max - min);
        var left1 = per1 * (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth) / 100;
        var left2 = per2 * (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth) / 100;

        button1.style.marginLeft = left1 + 'px';
        button2.style.marginLeft = left2 + 'px';

        if (left1 > left2) {
            between.style.width = (left1 - left2) + 'px';
            between.style.marginLeft = left2 + 'px';
        } else {
            between.style.width = (left2 - left1) + 'px';
            between.style.marginLeft = left1 + 'px';
        }
    }
    inpt2.onchange = function (evt) {
        if (parseInt(inpt2.value) < min)
            inpt2.value = min;
        if (parseInt(inpt2.value) > max)
            inpt2.value = max;
        if (parseInt(inpt1.value) > parseInt(inpt2.value)) {
            var temp = inpt1.value;
            inpt1.value = inpt2.value;
            inpt2.value = temp;
           
        }

        var sliderCoords = getCoords(slider);
        var per1 = parseInt(inpt1.value - min) * 100 / (max - min);
        var per2 = parseInt(inpt2.value - min) * 100 / (max - min);
        var left1 = per1 * (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth) / 100;
        var left2 = per2 * (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth) / 100;

        button1.style.marginLeft = left1 + 'px';
        button2.style.marginLeft = left2 + 'px';

        if (left1 > left2) {
            between.style.width = (left1 - left2) + 'px';
            between.style.marginLeft = left2 + 'px';
        } else {
            between.style.width = (left2 - left1) + 'px';
            between.style.marginLeft = left1 + 'px';
        }
    }

    /*mouse*/
    button1.onmousedown = function (evt) {
        var sliderCoords = getCoords(slider);
        var betweenCoords = getCoords(between);
        var buttonCoords1 = getCoords(button1);
        var buttonCoords2 = getCoords(button2);
        var shiftX2 = evt.pageX - buttonCoords2.left;
        var shiftX1 = evt.pageX - buttonCoords1.left;
       

        document.onmousemove = function (evt) { 
            var left1 = evt.pageX - shiftX1 - sliderCoords.left;
            var right1 = slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth;
            if (left1 < 0) left1 = 0;
            if (left1 > right1) left1 = right1;
            button1.style.marginLeft = left1 + 'px';


            shiftX2 = evt.pageX - buttonCoords2.left;
            var left2 = evt.pageX - shiftX2 - sliderCoords.left;
            var right2 = slider.offsetWidth - button2.offsetWidth;
            if (left2 < 0) left2 = 0;
            if (left2 > right2) left2 = right2;

            var per_min = 0;
            var per_max = 0;
            if (left1 > left2) {
                between.style.width = (left1 - left2) + 'px';
                between.style.marginLeft = left2 + 'px';

                per_min = left2 * 100 / (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth);
                per_max = left1 * 100 / (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth);
            } else {
                between.style.width = (left2 - left1) + 'px';
                between.style.marginLeft = left1 + 'px';

                per_min = left1 * 100 / (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth);
                per_max = left2 * 100 / (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth);
            }
            inpt1.value = (parseInt(min) + Math.round((max - min) * per_min / 100));
            inpt2.value = (parseInt(min) + Math.round((max - min) * per_max / 100));
           

        };
        document.onmouseup = function () {
            showInputRange(firstInputValue.value, secondInputValue.value)
            document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
        };
        return false;
    };

   

    button2.onmousedown = function (evt) {

        var sliderCoords = getCoords(slider);
        var betweenCoords = getCoords(between);
        var buttonCoords1 = getCoords(button1);
        var buttonCoords2 = getCoords(button2);
        var shiftX2 = evt.pageX - buttonCoords2.left;
        var shiftX1 = evt.pageX - buttonCoords1.left;

        document.onmousemove = function (evt) {
            var left2 = evt.pageX - shiftX2 - sliderCoords.left;
            var right2 = slider.offsetWidth - button2.offsetWidth;
            if (left2 < 0) left2 = 0;
            if (left2 > right2) left2 = right2;
            button2.style.marginLeft = left2 + 'px';


            shiftX1 = evt.pageX - buttonCoords1.left;
            var left1 = evt.pageX - shiftX1 - sliderCoords.left;
            var right1 = slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth;
            if (left1 < 0) left1 = 0;
            if (left1 > right1) left1 = right1;

            var per_min = 0;
            var per_max = 0;

            if (left1 > left2) {
                between.style.width = (left1 - left2) + 'px';
                between.style.marginLeft = left2 + 'px';
                per_min = left2 * 100 / (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth);
                per_max = left1 * 100 / (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth);
            } else {
                between.style.width = (left2 - left1) + 'px';
                between.style.marginLeft = left1 + 'px';
                per_min = left1 * 100 / (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth);
                per_max = left2 * 100 / (slider.offsetWidth - button1.offsetWidth);
            }
            inpt1.value = (parseInt(min) + Math.round((max - min) * per_min / 100));
            inpt2.value = (parseInt(min) + Math.round((max - min) * per_max / 100));
           


        };
        document.onmouseup = function () {
           
            showInputRange(firstInputValue.value, secondInputValue.value)
            document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
        };
        return false;
    };

    button1.ondragstart = function () {
        return false;
    };
    button2.ondragstart = function () {
        return false;
    };

    function getCoords(elem) {
        var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            top: box.top + pageYOffset,
            left: box.left + pageXOffset
        };
    }
   
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. Can anyone help please?